# Escaping Quotations in MySQL CSV import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to load a CSV into a MySQL table with the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/myfolder/tmp/data.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE `markers` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'# 2 rows affected.
```

However, when the script gets to line 44 it stops running (there are over 300 records in the CSV file). Line 44 contains a field with agent remarks and happens to have text with quotations in it. How can I escape these quotations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am using MyPHPAdmin to upload this CSV and it automatically includes another backslash, so there are two backslashes as shown in the code. Is this the problem? I tried manually removing the additional backslash and get an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\r\n'# 2 rows affected.' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

Occurrences of the `ENCLOSED BY` character within a field value are escaped by prefixing them with the `ESCAPED BY` character.

Alternatively, occurrences of the `ENCLOSED BY` character within a field value can be doubled and are interpreted as a single instance of the character.

Examples:

```
"The \"quoted\" string"
"The ""quoted"" string"
```

Comment: I understand the concept but the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command is not escaping the quotations in my CSV file as it should. I am not sure why this is the case. Thanks